# Vue router: Gulp uglify / watch node error

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, vue.js, vue-router

Just starting with Vue router and following the getting started but having issues straight away.

Using the same code as the example:

```
const Home = { template: '<div>Home</div>' }

const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: Home }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes // short for routes: routes
})

const app = new Vue({
    router
}).$mount('#app')
```

I have Gulp watch running which when saving the file throws this error in my terminal:

```
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error
at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/dev/Desktop/clients/ms-photography/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1545:18)
at js_error (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/dev/Desktop/clients/ms-photography/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1553:11)
at croak (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/dev/Desktop/clients/ms-photography/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2092:9)
at token_error (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/dev/Desktop/clients/ms-photography/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2100:9)
at expect_token (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/dev/Desktop/clients/ms-photography/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2113:9)
at expect (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/dev/Desktop/clients/ms-photography/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2116:36)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/dev/Desktop/clients/ms-photography/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2689:13)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/dev/Desktop/clients/ms-photography/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2139:24)
at expr_atom (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/dev/Desktop/clients/ms-photography/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2619:35)
at maybe_unary (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/dev/Desktop/clients/ms-photography/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2795:19)
```

This is my watch code in the gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
   return gulp.src('wp-content/themes/ms-photography/src/js/*.js')
    .pipe(minify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('wp-content/themes/ms-photography/dist/js/'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});
```

If I don't compile the scripts it works fine... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you need to add gulp-babel to your pipeline, i.e.

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-babel babel-preset-es2015
```

then:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('wp-content/themes/ms-photography/src/js/*.js')
    .pipe(babel({
        presets: ['es2015']
    }))
    .pipe(minify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('wp-content/themes/ms-photography/dist/js/'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});
```